# swift - Firebase database snapshot retrieval.

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure like below. This function below prints out everything in child node

```
func fetchUser() {

    ref.child("Businesses").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot)

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

But whenever I try to get the same snapshot for BusinessCategories and used the function below nothing happens. I have also tried adding .child("Banks") and still no print out and no error message.

```
func fetchUser() {

  ref.child("BusinessCategories").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot)

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? and how can I get snapshot of BusinessCategories?

[image]

Comment: I created a copy of your database in my own firebase project and everything works fine. The "BusinessCategories" has been printed. Please double check you did not make type mistake. Please show us a full class implementation maybe it will help. You can try to replace .childAdded with .value and let me know what is an effect

Comment: thank you I figured it out. Nothing was wrong with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. The problem was the test user was deleted from the authentication list and the app could not sign in to the database.